# Angular2 error interceptor not resending requests

Tags: angular, angular2-http

I have an angular2 error interceptor that catches all failures from my HTTP abstraction, my issue is when I'm catching the error and returning a new observable, the observables passed to .flatMap() are not being fired.

Here's an example of my http client implementation that makes the request:

```
return this._http.get(endpoint, data || {}, opts)
        .map(this.responseInterceptor)
        .catch(error => this.errorInterceptor({
            method: method,
            endpoint: endpoint,
            data: data || {},
            options: options
        }, error));
```

Here's the error interceptor

```
/**
 *
 * @param request
 * @param error
 * @returns {any}
 */
errorInterceptor(request: any, error: any): any {
    if (error.status === 401) {

        let tokenRequest = this.getToken({refresh_token: localStorage.getItem('refresh')}, 'refresh_token').map(res => {
                localStorage.setItem('token', res.access_token);
                localStorage.setItem('refresh', res.refresh_token);
                request.data.headers.set('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + res.access_token)
            })


        return tokenRequest.flatMap(res => this.request(request.method, request.endpoint, {}, request.data, false));
    }
    return this.handleError(error);
}
```

The issue is only the token request is being called, the request passed to `.flatMap()` never gets called.

I can work around the issue by doing:

```
tokenRequest.subscribe(res => {
    // logic here
    return this.request(...);
});
```

However, then the response structure changes which requires me to change code to handle pre-expiration requests and post-expiration, which is something I'd like to avoid.